# In App Purchase integration in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, sprite-kit, storekit

I need your advice for removing iAd using "In App purchase".
I have working code for "In App Purchase". But I dont know how to implement it into (IOS) SpriteKit Game. It is working great when I implement it in View Controller, but I need it  to work In MyScene.m so when I tap on button in "`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`" method "purchase" alert window would pup up and let player buy it

```
This code is working in Storyboard and has IBbutton but it is not seen in SKScene.
I am beginner developer and know how SKScene and MyScene but thats now enough.
If you want to look at code let me know thanks




Here is ny Code:
in View Controller.h I declare


    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>

{
    IBOutlet ADBannerView *iadBanner;
//   

}
@property ( nonatomic,strong) NSArray*products;

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSUserDefaults*defaults;


@end


In ViewController.m

    #import "MyNewlyCreatedScene.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize  /*idBanner*/ products,defaults;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:(id)self];

    defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    BOOL isPro=[defaults boolForKey:@"isPro"];



   if (!isPro) {
        //user code here
        [self fetchProducts];

} else {
        iadBanner.alpha=0.0;

}

}
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

    defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    BOOL isPro=[defaults boolForKey:@"isPro"];

    if (!isPro) {
        //user code here

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

          [banner setAlpha:1];

    [UIView commitAnimations];


    }

    else

    {

        iadBanner.alpha=0.0;

    }  

}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)fetchProducts{
    SKProductsRequest*request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet
 setWithArray:@[@"testingAppPurchaseID "]]];

    request.delegate = (id)self;

    [request start];
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{

    products = response.products;

    NSLog(@"Product was purchased");
}
-(void)request:(SKRequest*)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"%@",error);

}

-(void)buy:(SKProduct*)product{

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addPayment:payment];
}
-(IBAction)removeAdvertisment:(id)sender
{
    SKProduct *prod = [products objectAtIndex:0];

    [self buy:prod];
}
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *tx in transactions)   {

        switch (tx.transactionState) {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:tx];
               //_____________________
                iadBanner.alpha=0.0;
              //______________________

            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isPro"];
               break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:tx];

               NSLog(@"Error:%@",tx.error);

                        break;



            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:tx];

                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];``
    }

@end


In Storyboard I add iAdbannerView and a button and connect button to action, and set iAdbannerView to delegate


Give me some hints how to solve this problem.
```

I am sure there are a lot of developers why have games in app store and that means some of you Have IN App Purchase implemented in MyScene, so please help.

Comment: "If you want to look at code let me know" ... No, we **have** to look at the code. You are supposed to post your code if you have a problem with your code, how else can we suggest improvements and point out problems?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK to me.  You just need to run the

```
-(IBAction)removeAdvertisment:(id)sender
```

to trigger the purchase is that so?
you can hook an objC method call up to an SKAction by burying it in a block like so:

```
[SKAction runBlock:^ {
            [self removeAdvertisment:self];
        }]
```

then you could instruct some node or other (perhaps a textNode or spriteNode etc posing as a button) to run this action

I will mention two unrelated things you might want to think about...

1. one full second is quite a slow animation to remove an empty adBanner from the View.  I would halve that animation time (at least) if I were you.
2. If the purchase is to remove ads as it appears to be then you ought be checking the defaults before even creating the adBanner instance, and not ever adding one if the user already paid.  When the user makes the purchase you ought remove the banner completely and nil it out, a hidden banner serves no purpose other than to tie up RAM and potentially harm your revenues.

Comment: Thanks Jef for reply, I highly appreciate it, but question stays unanswered, I liked you suggestion on decreasing amimation time though. I was so busy implementing that method that I didnt even realised that I could do that, I thought it is how the code runs :), not really experiences programmer. There should some solutions to this. May be I could call some helper view controller like xib and all the code would be in xib oranother view controller and when I get to that view controller I could pless that buy button?